# How to get kubeadm to complete and launch the static pods defined in etc kubenertes manifests with containerd

Tags: fedora, kubernetes

Im working on fedora 30 (also tried fedora 29) and im unable to get past kubeadm init, this is the error i get:

```
kstarter]# kubeadm   init --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap,Service,Docker,SystemVerification,NumC PU --config=/root/con/cc.yaml 
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.14.1 [preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[WARNING Firewalld]: firewalld is active, please ensure ports [6443 10250] are open or your cluster may not function correctly 
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster 
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection 
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull' 
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env" 
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" 
[kubelet-start] Activating the kubelet service [certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"  
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key 
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key 
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key 
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key [certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [devks8twohundredandthirtyeighthbdhh99suy localhost] and IPs [172.16.6.3 127.0.0.1 ::1 ] 
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key [certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [devks8twohundredandthirtyeighthbdhh99suy localhost] and IPs [172.16.6.3 127.0.0.1 ::1] 
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key [certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key 
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [devks8twohundredandthirtyeighthbdhh99suy kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.defau lt.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [172.24.0.1 172.16.6.3] 
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key 
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key    
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key 
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key [kubeconfig] Using 
kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes" 
[kubeconfig] Writing  "admin.conf" kubeconfig file 
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file 
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf"  kubeconfig file 
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file 
[control-plane] Using manifest folder     "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" 
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver" 
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager" 
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler" 
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" 
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s 
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
     Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
       timed out waiting for the condition
     This error is likely caused by:
            - The kubelet is not running
            - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
     If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
            - 'systemctl status kubelet'
            - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'
     Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime. To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker. Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
            - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
            Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
            - 'docker logs CONTAINERID' error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
```

I can use containerd manually (with crictl) to launch containers in pods, and they work fine, but kubeadm creates /etc/kubernetes/manifests and nothing in there gets launched, why is this?  i can see anything in the logs to help debug.
here is the kubelet logs

- https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/lUXymIKk1SrZ76ELnW6t-Q and
- the containerd config: [containerd_fpaste](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/05Hzh8G49p9e4BMsQG1Iig)
- and  the --config passed to kubeadm init: [kubeadm_config_fpaste](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/VvkaqNVXmvvgV5FotOlXuw) and
- /var/lib/kubernetes/config.yaml: [var lib config](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/O85YNH3nnyyENai0lhduzQ)

Essentially im unable to get kubeadm to complete and looking at the output of crictl no containers/pods are created that should be created like kube api pod, etcd pod, no containers whatsoever are created, its like there is no connection between containerd and kubeadm, but im unable to see in the logs what im doing wrong.

```
- containerd-1.2.4-1.fc30.x86_64
- kubectl-1.14.1-0.x86_64
- kubeadm-1.14.1-0.x86_64
- kubelet-1.14.1-0.x86_64  all from google repository
```

with earlier versions of kubernetes (1.10X) and *containerd-cni* not (containerd) i could get kubeadm to create the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that  there was an issue here:

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
FailSwapOn: false
...
EnableControllerAttachDetach: true
StaticPodPath: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/"
```

that should be `staticPodPath` not `StaticPodPath`